# How to change specific table in Word 2016 using VBA

Tags: vba, microsoft-word-2016

I'm just start using VBA because I want to arrange the width of my table. After 2 hours I found this one works for me but the `Document.Tables` will apply this to all tables in document.

```
Sub resizeTables()  
  For Each Table In ActiveDocument.Tables  
    On Error Resume Next  
    Table.Columns(1).Width = 12.8  
    Table.Columns(2).Width = 22.7  
    Table.Columns(3).Width = 22.7  
    Table.Columns(4).Width = 227  
    Table.Columns(5).Width = 22.7  
    Table.Columns(6).Width = 227  
    On Error GoTo 0  
  Next  
End Sub
```

What should I use so this only change the 3rd table in a given document?

Comment: You likely could access each one directly with `ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(1).Width = 12.8` for example

Comment: It works. Thank you. For my code I change it to
Sub resizeTables()
    For Each Table In ActiveDocument.Tables
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(1).Width = 12.8
        ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(2).Width = 22.7
        ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(3).Width = 22.7
        ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(4).Width = 227
        ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(5).Width = 22.7
        ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(6).Width = 227
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub

Comment: I posted the code below, note that you do not need the for each loop since you are now directly accessing a specific table, not all tables in the document, so that part of the code becomes useless.  If left in, it will simply repeat the same steps once for each table that exists, but apply the changes only to table 3 each time.  Please mark the answer as accepted, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're looking for, completely remove the for each loop and access the table you want directly, as below:

```
Sub resizeTables()  
  On Error Resume Next  
  ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(1).Width = 12.8  
  ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(2).Width = 22.7  
  ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(3).Width = 22.7  
  ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(4).Width = 227  
  ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(5).Width = 22.7  
  ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Columns(6).Width = 227  
  On Error GoTo 0  
End Sub
```